# ssh localhost issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssh, authentication

I am trying to ssh to localhost, but it's asking for a password every time.

What I tried:

```
ssh localhost
ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa 
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `ssh -vv localhost`

Answer (score 5):

DSA keys are not accepted in recent versions of `openssh` by default. You should use `rsa`, which works fine and is considered more secure by the `openssh` developers. If you really want to use `dsa` keys, you should add

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

line into your `sshd_config` and restart `ssh` service.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you.
The way to discover this is that logging into the server with the `-vvv` flag has a line 
`debug3: receive packet: type 51`
inside of the output that reveals that the authentification failed.